# Is it "it" or "they" in this case?

Tags: pronouns

"budgeting and increasing revenue are important but **it** could harm..."

Does this sentence work with the prono

Answer (score 2):

It could be either, but there is an inconsistency in the sentence as it's written that makes it incorrect.

When you join two things together, you can choose to see them as a collective singular or as a simple conjunction of the two separate things.

For instance, both of the following are fine, with the right interpretation:

> Washing and drying clothes *is a* tedious *chore*.
>   Washing and drying clothes *are* tedious *chores*.

In the first sentence, *washing and drying* is being treated as a single collective action, whereas in the second sentence it is is being treated as a group of two individual actions.

Some things are more commonly thought of as single collective items, while others are more commonly thought of as groups of individual items.

---

The same is true of your example sentence. The way you interpret it needs to be applied consistently.

So:

> ✔ . . . budgeting and increasing revenue **are** important but **they** could harm . . .
>   ✔ . . . budgeting and increasing revenue **is** important but **it** could harm . . .

But not:

> ✘ . . . budgeting and increasing revenue **are** important but **it** could harm . . .
>   ✘ . . . budgeting and increasing revenue **is** important but **they** could harm . . .

Answer (score 1):

The sentence does not start with a capital letter, but I am going to answer as if the sentence starts with the word "Budgeting".  The correct word in this case is "they", because more than one thing was mentioned as being important, and people would expect that the "but xx may" part of the sentence should be referring to all of those important things.  If one uses "it" here, in US english at least, it would leave one to wonder which of the important things, "budgeting" or "increasing revenue" the "but xx may" was talking about, because it seems to only be talking about one thing.
If the "it" in "but it may" actually is not talking about both "budgeting" and "increasing revenue", or is talking about something else, like someone's suggested plan of action, then some word more specific than "it" should be used, so the reader can be certain of the meaning.